# Input amount of coins and output amount in dollars & cents

Tags: c++

I am wondering why my code isn't displaying the amount in cents and only displaying the amount in dollars. Anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
int dollars;
int change;
int quarters;
int dimes;
int nickels;
int pennies;

cout << "Enter amount of quaters" << endl;
cin >> quarters;

cout << "Enter amount of dimes" << endl;
cin >> dimes;

cout << "Enter amount of nickels" << endl;
cin >> nickels;

cout << "Enter amount of pennies" << endl;
cin >> pennies;

quarters = quarters * 0.25;
dimes = dimes * 0.10;
nickels = nickels * 0.05;
pennies = pennies * 0.01;

dollars = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;
change = dollars % quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

cout << "You have " << dollars << " dollar(s)" << endl;
cout << "You have " << change << " cents" << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: If you compute amounts in cents you're more likely to get the correct answer here. Dollars is `cents / 100` and cents remaining is `cents % 100`. Floating point values and money are not friends, they can cause a lot of conflict.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you will have to extract a [mcve] first, because as it stands it is considered off-topic.

Comment: You are losing data by assigning floating point values to variables of type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `dimes = dimes * 0.10;`, `dimes` is still an `int` and cannot represent fractional amounts. You will want to store them in a `float` instead.

Here's an example:

```
int dimes_int = 2;
float dimes_float = dimes_int * 0.1;
dimes_int = dimes_float;//convert the floating point number to an integer.

std::cout << dimes_float << ' ' << dimes_int << '\n';
```

You should get `0.2 0` as your output.

For more serious finance calculations, there are lots of difficulties using floating point types with roundoff errors, but I suspect in your case this isn't a big deal.